# Tag badges curiosities

Tags: support, tagging, badges

In [Help Center > Badges](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/badges) one finds rules of earning tag badges:

- `Bronze Badge`

You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

- `Silver Badge`

You must have a total score of 400 in at least 80 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

- `Gold Badge`

You must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

So far, I've earned `5` bronze badges in `functions`, `calculus-and-analysis`, `equation-solving`, `plotting` and `list-manipulation` tags.

I'm curious why I still haven't earned a bronze badge in `polynomials` tag. There I have `23` answers and over `100` total upvotes. Similarily, in `algebraic-manipulation` tag I have `20` answers and more than `100` total upvotes.

**Could you explain if the tag badges rules have been fulfilled in case of e.g. polynomial tag?**

I really don't miss much those badges, I just simply want to understand the stackexchange rules.

Comment: @rm-rf Info from sidebar is not all. There is gold badge for `list-manipulation` while `plotting` has more questions.

Comment: @Kuba The sidebar describes the requirements for a tag to be eligible for any badge. Once it is eligible, the gold/silver/bronze badges depend on the users' score. In this case, it so happened that Mr.Wizard got to 1000 votes and 200 answers in [tag:list-manipulation] first before [tag:plotting]. Note that it is **and** – I'll hit 1000 votes in [tag:list-manipulation] very soon, but I won't get a gold badge yet since I still have a little over 50 answers that I need to write in order to be eligible :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tag itself should have a minimum of 100 questions to be awarded any badge. You'll get all eligible badges when each of them reach 100 questions. This is explained in the sidebar

> These badges are awarded for participating in non community-wiki questions with particular tags. If enough votes are earned in a tag with 100+ total questions, the badge will be automatically created and awarded.